# Jquery submits form but does not fade my div

Tags: php, jquery

The title almost says it all. I have a jquery code i've written, im not good at it but this is what i achieved:

```
$("#myForm").submit(function(){

            //alert($(this).serialize());

            $.post("submit.php", $(this).serialize(), function(data){
                if(data == success) {

                $("#add_vote").fadeOut("fast");
                $("#verification_sent").fadeIn("fast");
                $("#wrong").fadeOut("fast");

                } else {

                $("#wrong").fadeIn("fast");

                }
            });

            return false;
        });
```

The form gets submitted well but the fadeIn and fadeOut's I have does not work. Do anyone know why?

Comment: What's the value of the variable called `success` supposed to be? Where is it defined in your code?

Comment: I print success in the php file. Is that not the way it's supposed to work?

Comment: @Paparappa - Then you need to put `"success"` in quotes. It's a string, not a JavaScript variable.

Comment: If you print the string success in your php file, you want to compare data to the string success, so: `data == 'success'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is `success` in:

```
if(data == success) {
```

Maybe you mean:

```
if(data == "success") {
```

Or else you maybe have misunderstood the `$.post` function?

```
 $.post("submit.php", $(this).serialize(), function(data){
```

Lets break it up:

```
 "submit.php" // the url (OK)
 $(this).serialize() // The data (OK)
 function(data){ // The callback on success
```

And its only a helper function for the `$.ajax` method, Witch also have a error callback:

```
var ajaxObj = $.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: "submit.php",
  data: $(this).serialize()
});
ajaxObj.success(function(){
    // Success
});
ajaxObj.error(function(){
    // Error
});
```

Comment: I've added quotes to success cause that was what i meant. But my div still wont fade. And i print "success" in the php file.

Answer (score 3):

Verify what submit.php returns, and what is in `data`.

```
if(data == success) {
```

This looks suspicious, did you meant `if (data == "success") {` ? (`success` is a variable, probably undefined; `"success"` is a string.)

Comment: i meant with quotes and i changed it, still didn't work though. Hmm.

Comment: then check what submit.php returned, check what is in `data`.